# How to select specific index in a multidimensional array in asp.net using vb

Tags: asp.net, arrays, vb.net, multidimensional-array

I cannot explain well in the title so i'll explain here the scenario:

In here, i have a query that will be placed in an array.

```
 Dim arrUsers As Object = {{sqlReader("dephead"), dropdown1}, {sqlReader("mm"), dropdown2}
```

I want to enable the dropdown object if it matches my if else condition:

```
'indexes1= the 1st indexes of each pair in the array (the sqlReaders)
'indexes2= my dropdown objects in my user control

For Each indexes1 In arrUsers
            If Session.Item("EmployeeID") = indexes1 Then
                indexes2.Enabled = True
            End If
Next
```

so lets say the my session id will be "dephead", then the dropdown1 will be enabled. Thats what i would like to happen but im not familiar on arrays so kindly help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
For i As Integer = 0 to arrUsers.GetUpperBound(0)
    If Session.Item("EmployeeID") = arrUsers(i)(0) Then
        arrUsers(i)(1).Enabled = True
    End If
Next
```

You simply give the array two indexes instead of one. `arrUsers(0)(1)`, for example. The first index returns the object at that index, and the second index returns the object inside the previously returned array. `arrUsers(0)(1)` will first grab the array at 0 index (`{sqlReader("dephead"), dropdown1}`), then get the object at index 1 (`dropdown1`).

Comment: it's not working for me @RianBattle, should i add some codes?

Comment: there is an error occured: "Attempted to operate on an array with the incorrect number of dimensions."

Answer (score 0):

This answered my question. The answer above helped me and i just changed the declaration of my arrays and changed some syntax.

```
Dim arrUsers(,) As Object =
    New Object(,) {
                                 {sqlReader("dephead"), dropdown1}, _
                                 {sqlReader("mm"), dropdown2}, _
                                 }

        Dim bound0 As Integer = arrUsers.GetUpperBound(0)
        Dim bound1 As Integer = arrUsers.GetUpperBound(1)

For i As Integer = 0 To bound0

                If Session.Item("EmployeeID") = arrUsers(i, 0) Then
                    arrUsers(i, 1).Enabled = True
                End If

Next
```